# How to continue a batch file pause in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a PowerShell script which creates a development environment and part of the process is to call a batch file to get source code. The problem is the batch file calls another batch file which has a `pause` at the end of it. This means the PowerShell script will not move on to the next task.

I can't remove the pause from the batch file as it is maintained by a different team.

I have created another batch file which gets around the pause issue:

```
    @echo OFF

    @echo Calling test.cmd...
    @echo | call test.cmd
    @echo Done.
```

Is there a way in PowerShell to do this so I don't need my batch file?

**PowerShell script**

```
Invoke-Expression -command "d:\relay.cmd"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it the same way in PowerShell. Pass something by the pipeline:

```powershell
@()|.\test.cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering to an old question because I had a similar problem.

You can use the `echo` and pass someting as the parameter. So, following also does the trick:

```
echo "" | .\test.cmd
```

Comment: Is that the case for powershell? I'm getting: `echo/: The term 'echo/' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Comment: The question is about PowerShell so that should be taken.

Comment: Had you read the question? It's about running a batch file with PowerShell.